# jQuery selectors for MVC generated select works for one dropdown, but not for another

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a rather odd issue with using an MVC dropdown list generated with the `@HTML.EnumDropDownListFor()` method with JQuery selectors.  I have multiple dropdown lists on a partial view.  However, when I use a jQuery selector to get the value of the first dropdown (`QuestionType`), it returns the original (default) value of the dropdown instead of the selected value.  The other two dropdowns (`AnswerCommentType` and `Status`) return the selected values with no problems.  I did some further testing using the `.change()` event to see if the event was triggered with the jQuery selector.  The `.change()` event was triggered with `$("select").change()`, but not with the `$("#QuestionType").change()` selector.  Also, I took a look at the raw HTML code to see if there was any difference between the three select tags generated by MVC; there is no significant difference.  Anyone have any idea what could be going on here?

Here is the HTML of the section with the dropdowns from the partial view:

```
        <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 nopadding">
                <span>Question Type:</span><br />
                @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(x => x.QuestionType)<br />
                <span>Answer Type:</span><br />
                @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(x => x.AnswerCommentType)<br />
                <span>Sequence:</span><br />
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.DisplayOrder)<br />
                <span>Activity Status:</span><br />
                @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(x => x.Status)<br />
                <span>Short Display Text:</span><br />
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ShortDisplayText)<br />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 nopadding">
                <span>Options:</span><br />
                @Html.ListBox("Options", new SelectList(Model.OptionValues))<br />
                <input type="button" id="addOption" value="Add" />
                <input type="button" id="removeOption" value="Remove" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

`$("#QuestionType").val()` always returns `"0"` regardless of what option is selected.
`$("#AnswerCommentType").val()` always returns the selected option.
`$("#Status").val()` always returns the selected option.

and, here is a copy of the test jQuery events:

```
//Responds to all select change events
$("select").change(function () {
    debugger;
});

//Responds to AnswerCommentType change events
$("#AnswerCommentType").change(function () {
    debugger;
});

//Never responds
$("#QuestionType").change(function () {
    debugger;
});
```

Finally, here is a copy of the raw HTML code for QuestionType and AnswerCommentType generated by MVC:

```
<div class="col-md-6 nopadding">

<span>Question Type:</span><br>
<select name="QuestionType" id="QuestionType" data-val-required="The QuestionType field is required." data-val="true">
    <option selected="selected" value="0"></option>
    <option value="1">Customer</option>
    <option value="2">EquipmentFrontDriver</option>
    <option value="3">EquipmentRearDriver</option>
    <option value="4">EquipmentFrontPassenger</option>
    <option value="5">EquipmentRearPassenger</option>
    <option value="6">Front</option>
    <option value="7">Rear</option>
    <option value="8">DriverSide</option>
    <option value="9">PassengerSide</option>
    <option value="10">Receive</option>
    <option value="11">Position1</option>
    <option value="12">Position2</option>
    <option value="13">Position3</option>
    <option value="14">Position4</option>
    <option value="15">Position5</option>
    <option value="16">Position6</option>
    <option value="17">Position7</option>
    <option value="18">Position8</option>
    <option value="19">Position9</option>
    <option value="20">Position10</option>
    <option value="21">Position11</option>
    <option value="22">Position12</option>
    <option value="23">Position13</option>
    <option value="24">Position14</option>
    <option value="25">Position15</option>
    <option value="26">Position16</option>
    <option value="27">Step2</option>
</select><br>

<span>Answer Type:</span><br>
<select name="AnswerCommentType" id="AnswerCommentType" data-val-required="The AnswerCommentType field is required." data-val="true">
    <option selected="selected" value="0">Header</option>
    <option value="1">YesNo</option>
    <option value="2">OkFix</option>
    <option value="3">None</option>
    <option value="4">Level1Checkbox</option>
</select><br>

<span>Sequence:</span><br>
<input name="DisplayOrder" id="DisplayOrder" type="text" value="0" data-val-required="The DisplayOrder field is required." data-val="true" data-val-number="The field DisplayOrder must be a number."><br>

<span>Activity Status:</span><br>
<select name="Status" id="Status" data-val-required="The Status field is required." data-val="true">
    <option selected="selected" value="0">Active</option>
    < option value="1">Inactive</option>
</select><br>

<span>Short Display Text:</span><br>
<input name="ShortDisplayText" id="ShortDisplayText" type="text" value=""><br>
```

I see no significant difference that could cause this issue.  Also, I verified this behavior is the same on both Internet Explorer and Chrome.  I'm using jQuery-3.1.0, jQuery-ui-1.12.0 and MVC 4.5.2.  Any ideas?

Comment: Can you check if there's any other element with `id="QuestionType"` in the whole page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check with **same id="QuestionType"** exist in page? as per **@ekad**.

If not, register **change event after dom complete load** as below:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    setTimeout(function () {
        $("#QuestionType").change(function () {
            debugger;
        });
    }, 500);
});
```

Comment: Yep, that was indeed the problem.  I was searching all over the partial view for a duplicate name.  The partial view is used as a dialog popup, and the duplicate name was on main view.  Thanks, this should have been an obvious one.